# Using SetFetchMode

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, fetch

Excuse my amateur nhibernate-ness but I am struggling with fetching in the below scenario.

```
var query = session.CreateCriteria<Notification>().SetFetchMode("Parameters", FetchMode.Select)
.CreateAlias("Parameters", "p", JoinType.InnerJoin)
.Add(Restrictions.Where<Notification>(x => x.Acknowledged == false));
```

[some code that builds an IList called npHashes]

```
query = query.Add(Restrictions.In("p.PairHash", npHashes)).AddOrder(new Order("DateCreated", false));
```

[enumerate it]

Note that I am using SELECT as the prefetchmode... an option that apparently got left out of QueryOver... and LINQ... Also note the fetched table is the same table that i have joined on to to filter by.

Executing that query results in this:

```
    SELECT
    this_.Id as Id14_1_,
    this_.Version as Version14_1_,
    this_.Url as Url14_1_,
    this_.DispatchType as Dispatch5_14_1_,
    this_.Acknowledged as Acknowle6_14_1_,
    this_.DateCreated as DateCrea7_14_1_,
    this_.NotificationType as Notifica2_14_1_,
    p1_.Id as Id15_0_,
    p1_.Version as Version15_0_,
    p1_.NotificationId as Notifica3_15_0_,
    p1_.Name as Name15_0_,
    p1_.Value as Value15_0_,
    p1_.PairHash as PairHash15_0_ 
FROM
    Notification this_ 
inner join
    NotificationParameter p1_ 
        on this_.Id=p1_.NotificationId 
WHERE
    this_.Acknowledged = ?p0 
    and p1_.PairHash in (
        ?p1
    ) 
ORDER BY
    this_.DateCreated desc;
?p0 = False [Type: Boolean (0)],
?p1 = 'V3zmXnv12B3AC26xeG10w+bas4U=' [Type: String (28)]
```

So the first issue is for some reason NotificationParameter columns are included in the select list... it appears to not be doing a select fetch. This is bad because a) i want a select fetch b) the fetch records are filtered. Fetching is not the same as joining (as a concept) and the filters on the joined data should not (in this case) be filtering what I fetch.

Second issue of course is the SELECT fetch didn't happen. Instead on first accessing of the Parameters property of Notification they are lazily loaded :O

Any help? Also if theres a way to do this using QueryOver i'd prefer that. I noticed that I could go .UnderlyingCriteria.SetFetchmode(....) however that had no effect on what was fetched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in sql you cant filter and fetch all at the same time. I'm not that familiar with query over yet but you should get the idea.

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<Notification>()
    .CreateAlias("Parameters", "p", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.Where<Notification>(x => x.Acknowledged == false))
    .Add(Restrictions.In("p.PairHash", npHashes))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Id());

session.CreateCriteria<Notification>()
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", subquery))
    .SetFetchMode("Parameters", FetchMode.Eager)
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("DateCreated"))
    .List<Notification>();
```

Comment: I'll try that out... however as I am doing a SELECT fetch (not eager with i think maps to an outer join) filtering and fetching at the same shouldn't affect each other.